Moving and rotating a hyperplane so it intercepts the vertices of a hypercube
Let a vector $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a scalar value $b \in \mathbb{R}$ define a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$:
$$\mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{x} = a_1\,x_1 + a_2\,x_2 + \dots + a_n\,x_n = b$$
Consider that this hyperplane is dividing the space in two parts, such that we are interested in the subdomain defined by the inequality:
$$\mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{x} \leq b$$
This will exclude from the subdomain part of the vertices of the unit hypercube given by:
$$0\leq x_i \leq 1, \forall i\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$$
(in extreme cases, it may exclude none of the vertices, or all of them)

My goal is to find a new hyperplane $\mathbf{c}^T\,\mathbf{x} = d$ such that $\mathbf{c}^T\,\mathbf{x} \leq d$ excludes the same vertices of the hypercube than the original inequality, while intercepting the maximal possible number of vertices of the hypercube.
In other words, I want the intersection between these domains to have the same (non-excluded) vertices than the hypercube.
In other other words, I want that the intersection operation between these domains only exclude hypercube vertices without creating any new ones.

What I have tried
The vertices of the hypercube are all the $2^n$ points with only binary values: $\mathbf{x} \in\{0,1\}^n$.
This means that $\mathbf{a}^T\,\mathbf{x}$ will be a sum of the entries of $\mathbf{a}$. I can then divide these entries in three sets, with positive ($P$), negative ($Q$) and zero ($R$) values: $P=\{p_1,p_2,\dots\}$, $Q=\{q_1,q_2,\dots\}$ and $R=\{0,0,...\}$.
The zero-valued entries can be disregarded for now. I then look for ways of adding terms of $P$ and $Q$ such that I get the highest possible value that is still less or equal to $b$, finding $b^*$. Except for very particular cases, $b^*$ will be lower than $b$, which means that we can translate the hyperplane until it intercepts the closest vertex of the hypercube. The result is the translated hyperplane, parallel to the original one:
$$\mathbf{a}^T\,\mathbf{x} = b^*$$
This should put the hyperplane on at least one vertex of the hypercube, but I need to rotate my hyperplane to get more vertices.
The intercepted vertex $\mathbf{x^*}$ is known, it is the vertex related to the terms that were added together to achieve $b^*$. Thus, $\mathbf{c}$ and $d$ must be such that $\mathbf{c}^T\,\mathbf{x^*} = d$.
I am not sure how to rotate this hyperplane until it intercepts the next vertex. In the the worst case scenario, we should keep applying rotations until $n$ different verices of the hypercube be intercepted by the hyperplane.

I suspect the optimization problem variant of the Subset Sum problem is embedded in this problem.  In particular, restricting the $x_i$ to ${-1,1}$, to pick out the vertices of the unit hypercube should be equivalent to optimizing a subset sum for ${2a_1, 2a_2, \dots}$.

In my case, I have real values and an inequality constraint, so it may be somewhat different from the subset sum problem.
I am free to translate and re-scale any axis of my hypercube, so if things get easier for a specific hyperrectangle, I am open to suggestions! About that, an alternate problem would be moving and re-scaling the hypercube so that we put its vertices on the fixed hyperplane...
